Local installation of an R package outputs Rcpp conversion error
I'm trying to install this Atoms package (see Github link: https://github.com/julienide/Atoms) and I'm new to R.
My computer is a mac (M1 chip).
So far, I've successfully installed all dependencies through Rstudio using the CRAN repository. Precision: i was a bit messy when I did it and some dependencies were installed as binaries, others in sources, but I don't think it would make any difference. Atoms being unavailable in CRAN I guessed I had to install it locally.
The installation through the Rstudio interface seems to be successful but when I try to load the library on the Rstudio console:
> library(Atoms)
*Error in library(Atoms) : there is no package called ‘Atoms’
In addition: Warning message:
In install.packages(file.choose(), "/Users/USERNAME/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library",  :
  installation of package ‘/Users/USERNAME/R_studio_topology_MAKER/Atoms_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status*

Okay, maybe I'll get more information via the R CMD INSTALL on the terminal command about said error. I obtain a chunky output describing installation processes until I obtain two errors:
% R CMD INSTALL PATH-TO-TAR.GZ Atoms_1.0.tar.gz

*PDBWriter.cpp:15:19: error: conversion from 'Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::S4_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>>::SlotProxy' to 'Rcpp::DataFrame' (aka 'DataFrame_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>') is ambiguous
  Rcpp::DataFrame atoms = x.slot("atoms") ;
                  ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/USERNAME/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/proxy/SlotProxy.h:42:31: note: candidate function [with T = Rcpp::DataFrame_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>]
        template <typename T> operator T() const;
                              ^
/Users/USERNAME/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:51:9: note: candidate constructor [with T = Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::S4_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>>::SlotProxy]
        DataFrame_Impl( const T& obj ) ;
        ^
PDBWriter.cpp:106:19: error: conversion from 'Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::S4_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>>::SlotProxy' to 'Rcpp::DataFrame' (aka 'DataFrame_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>') is ambiguous
  Rcpp::DataFrame bonds = x.slot("bonds") ;
                  ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/USERNAME/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/proxy/SlotProxy.h:42:31: note: candidate function [with T = Rcpp::DataFrame_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>]
        template <typename T> operator T() const;
                              ^
/Users/USERNAME/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:51:9: note: candidate constructor [with T = Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::S4_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>>::SlotProxy]
        DataFrame_Impl( const T& obj ) ;
        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [PDBWriter.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Atoms’
* removing ‘/Users/USERNAME/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/Atoms’*

I tried to do some light modifications in this PDBWriter.cpp script based on some discussions, then compressing the whole directory and trying again to install but it got way worse. At this stage I am completely clueless but I have a couple more options:
1- Load each R script on the script I want to run. But they depend on some C++ scripts and I have no idea how to set up everything
2- Use this githubinstall function but I get:
> library(githubinstall)
> githubinstall("julienide/Atoms")
Suggestion:
 - juliengoo/test  
Do you want to install the package (Y/n)?  n
cancelled by user
-> The githubinstall doesn't find the correct package

3- Use this devtools package but i think it proposes the same githubinstall function. Correct me if I'm wrong
If you know of a page where a similar issue was solved I'll be happy to investigate it a bit more deeply. If you have a clever solution please suggest it I'll try my best to apply it. In the meantime I'll be chipping away at the problem.

Actually, it's devtools::install_github or remotes::install_github.

Hello Rui and thx for the correction. I did find the correct way to write the command but stumbled into a different error

Can you post the command and that new error?

The command:
> devtools::install_github('julienide/Atoms')
produces exactly the same conversion error message on the Rstudio terminal than the RCMD INSTALL command (see my original message)
I obtain some comments though, as in suggestions to what might be the problem (see next comment). But I don't find it very useful

Warning messages: 1: In check_encoding(self, private, NULL) :   Consider adding an Encoding field to DESCRIPTION, Non-ASCII character(s) in Author@R 2: In check_encoding(self, private, NULL) :   Consider adding an Encoding field to DESCRIPTION, Non-ASCII character(s) in Author@R 3: In check_encoding(self, private, NULL) :   Consider adding an Encoding field to DESCRIPTION, Non-ASCII character(s) in Author@R 4: In i.p(...) :   installation of package ‘/var/folders/gb/1kdkj1sd5xd8y3smv76s2ktr0000gn/T//RtmpoGxpSg/filedf0f6b835fe5/Atoms_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I might have done something wrong in my first attempts.  I remember getting a different error but I can't replicate it nor remember it detail
